# Dropbox python sdk import error

Tags: python, api, sdk, dropbox, importerror

I am trying to use the dropbox sdk for python. I installed a virtual enviroment and used pip install to install dropbox-sdk. When I try to run the example code (see below) I get a importerror client cannot be found, but if I try to do it from the interactive intreperter it works. So what am I doing wrong. APP key and secret key and acces_type ommitted.

Comment: and you're certain you're activating the virtual environment before you run the code?

Comment: yes I am sure, I even tried a global installation en running it then but I get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: I found the problem, i called my own file dropbox.py and in that file imported dropbox. I accidently imported my own file. Renamed my file and now it works.